# how to cut plugin (head) from lan cable (for internet)?

Tags: cable-modem

Is there easy way to cut plugin from cable, if it possible without pincers? I want to cut from cable which is bought in shop, and put on cable which came from wall?

Comment: You can buy separate ehternet cable ends and just spools of cable to make your own ethernet cables which is what you are more or less trying to do. Just do a google search for the ends

Comment: Well then I suppose you could strip the wires, and connect them all to their cooresponding color. Do use butt end connectors though at the very least...

Comment: Why dat people who put down vote, not leave comment???

Comment: if they're both the same connector, why bother - if they're not the same connector, what makes you think they're compatible?? [in answer to your comment, because it shows no knowledge or research. You didn't even say what the connectors are]

Comment: Why not use a wall jack? Ten times as elegant, (literally) no strings attached. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no. As Eric has said cables are made up of cable and ends (RJ45) when the end goes on a crimping tool is used to lock the wires in place. The plastic that is pushed down by the crimper doesn't go back up so you probably wont be able to feed the wires through.